# Preserving cookies in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, cookies, uiwebview

So I have an `UIWebView` in my app, it has a PHP Session inside it. I was under the impression these cookies would be kept for as long as the user has the app open.

But whats happening is the user is filling out a form, locking their phone for a while or switching in out and then back into the app. But then for some reason the cookie is then missing and the session gets reset and they have to restart.

Is there anything I could be doing wrong?

Or is there any way I could save the cookies after every page load, then restore them every time the user views the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else stumbles across this when trying to fix this for themselves, I opted to fix it using JavaScript on the webpage.

First Include this in your base HTML file, or use a php file to put it in every page on your site:(Since you cant use php headers inside a js file.)

```
<script>
    function get_SID(){
        return '<?php echo session_id(); ?>';
    }
    function get_session_name(){
        return '<?php echo session_name(); ?>';
    }
</script>
```

Then add this code to one of your base JS files:

```
<script>
   function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
       var d = new Date();
       d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
       var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
       document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires + "; path=/";
   }
   function refresh_cookie(){
       setCookie(get_session_name(), get_SID(), 10000);
   }
</script>
```

Hope this helps someone else.